# GUI programs are blurry pixelated in WSL2

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So I am running WSL2 in Windows 11. I have tried to run  GUI programs such as TexStudio. It had the same issues but not to the extent that I am having with matplotlib. They are super pixelated and are not displaying correctly. I am at loss on how to fix it. These programs are basically unusable due to the amount of unreadable/usable screen.

Here are a few example images. Sometimes when I click on an image it will go clear until I click on another aspect of it.  Using the save feature is basically impossible.
Blurry Image 1:

[image: Blurry Image 1]

Blurry Image 2:

[image: Blurry Image 2]

I changed the display so
`echo $DISPLAY`
outputs :0

What I read is that I don't need x11 since I am on windows 11.

Thoughts on  how to resolve this?

Comment: this is not "blurry". this is "displaying garbage". it is very different question. (but still, off topic here - please try asking on superuser.com - and add details about your configurations)